# Facing issues with IBM blockchain platform at vs code in my-asset-contract.ts

Tags: blockchain, ibm-blockchain

just started learning blockchain through IBM blockchain platform at VS code and facing issues with the code. I did everything according to the tutorial and had no clue how to resolve them.

Here is the code

```
/*
 * SPDX-License-Identifier: Apache-2.0
 */

import { Context, Contract, Info, Returns, Transaction } from 'fabric-contract-api';
import { MyAsset } from './my-asset';

@Info({title: 'MyAssetContract', description: 'My Smart Contract' })
export class MyAssetContract extends Contract {

    @Transaction(false)
    @Returns('boolean')
    public async myAssetExists(ctx: Context, myAssetId: string): Promise<boolean> {
        const data: Uint8Array = await ctx.stub.getState(myAssetId);
        return (!!data && data.length > 0);
    }

    @Transaction()
    public async createMyAsset(ctx: Context, myAssetId: string, value: string): Promise<void> {
        const exists: boolean = await this.myAssetExists(ctx, myAssetId);
        if (exists) {
            throw new Error(`The my asset ${myAssetId} already exists`);
        }
        const myAsset: MyAsset = new MyAsset();
        myAsset.value = value;
        const buffer: Buffer = Buffer.from(JSON.stringify(myAsset));
        await ctx.stub.putState(myAssetId, buffer);
    }

    @Transaction(false)
    @Returns('MyAsset')
    public async readMyAsset(ctx: Context, myAssetId: string): Promise<MyAsset> {
        const exists: boolean = await this.myAssetExists(ctx, myAssetId);
        if (!exists) {
            throw new Error(`The my asset ${myAssetId} does not exist`);
        }
        const data: Uint8Array = await ctx.stub.getState(myAssetId);
        const myAsset: MyAsset = JSON.parse(data.toString()) as MyAsset;
        return myAsset;
    }

    @Transaction()
    public async updateMyAsset(ctx: Context, myAssetId: string, newValue: string): Promise<void> {
        const exists: boolean = await this.myAssetExists(ctx, myAssetId);
        if (!exists) {
            throw new Error(`The my asset ${myAssetId} does not exist`);
        }
        const myAsset: MyAsset = new MyAsset();
        myAsset.value = newValue;
        const buffer: Buffer = Buffer.from(JSON.stringify(myAsset));
        await ctx.stub.putState(myAssetId, buffer);
    }

    @Transaction()
    public async deleteMyAsset(ctx: Context, myAssetId: string): Promise<void> {
        const exists: boolean = await this.myAssetExists(ctx, myAssetId);
        if (!exists) {
            throw new Error(`The my asset ${myAssetId} does not exist`);
        }
        await ctx.stub.deleteState(myAssetId);
    }

}
```

Error 1
[image]

Error 2
[image]

Error 3
[image]

Error 4
[image]

Error 5
[image]

Comment: looks like you have to run npm install on your project. So open a terminal and go to the directory where your project is (it will have package.json file) and run the command `npm install`

Comment: Hi @david_k
tried command npm install
still getting the below error

npm : The term 'npm' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program. Check the 
spelling of the name, or if a path was included, verify that the path is correct and try again.
At line:1 char:1
+ npm install
+ ~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (npm:String) [], CommandNotFoundException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : CommandNotFoundException

Comment: Looks like either you don't have Node.js installed or it's not on your PATH